# Use a Unicode character in a char variable (C++)

Tags: c++, unicode

I get some input from the command line and want to support Unicode.

This is my error:

[image: Repl.it output error]

And this is my example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char test = '█';
} 

// Characters wanted: █, ▓, or ▒
```

How can I make my program support Unicode?

Comment: Char only holds one bit. Try wide char and wcout.

Comment: Only use Unicode in strings in UTF-8 format. Types like wchar don’t help much because Unicode characters can be multiple code points. ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: `wchar_t` works just fine for Unicode, as long as you take into account that `wchar_t` is different sizes on different platforms (16 bits on Windows, 32 bits on others), so use `std::wstring` instead of a single `wchar_t` so you can account for the possibility of needing multiple `wchar_t`s to encode a single Unicode codepoint, and multiple codepints to encode a single Unicode grapheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `char` is usually only 1 byte, meaning it won't be able to store most Unicode characters. You should look into using `wchar_t` which is required to be large enough to hold any supported character codepoint. The associated char literal looks as follows: `L'█'`.

Comment: What about L'‍‍‍'?

Comment: ‍‍‍ is not a single codepoints, but 8 codepoints making up what your browser likely shows as one emoticon, thus it can't be stored in a character type and must be stored in a string.

Comment: "*`wchar_t` ... is required to be large enough to hold any supported character codepoint*" - that is not the case on Windows, where `wchar_t` is only 16 bits, so it can't hold Unicode codepoints > U+FFFF, but it can hold UTF-16 code units, which is why Unicode `wchar_t` strings on Windows are encoded in UTF-16 (previously UCS-2), whereas other platforms can encode `wchar_t` strings using UTF-32 instead.

Comment: `A char is usually only 1 byte` char is always exactly 1 byte.

Comment: It depends on the definitions you use, as per the standard a byte is defined as an `addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment` and a char is defined as `single-byte character <C> bit representation that fits in a byte`. However, the common definition of a byte defines it as containing 8 bits, which is not necessarily equivalent to the definition in the standard.